# Como usar a função svymean() se possuo missings nas observações?

Tags: r

Estou usando a função **svymean()** do pacote **Survey** porém quando os dados possuem *missings* ("NA"), a média não é calculada.

Por favor, alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

A função `svymean` tem um argumento `na.rm`que por padrão é `FALSE`, ou seja se você não citar o argumento na chamada da função, ele utilizará o valor `FALSE`. Se você fizer

```
svymean(..., na.rm = T)
```

Ela deve fazer o cálculo excluindo as observações com missing, o que deve resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Daniel está correta: basta acrescentar o parâmetro `na.rm = TRUE`. Só acrescento que deve-se tomar cuidado ao utilizar esse parâmetro quando analisamos mais de 1 variável ao mesmo tempo (não sei se é o caso), pois o `survey` remove a observação que possui `NA` em pelo menos 1 das variáveis analisadas, mesmo que em outra variável ela não seja missing. Por exemplo:

```
require(survey)
exemplo <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, var = rnorm(10), var2 = rnorm(10, 5), peso = rchisq(10, 5))
exemplo[10, 2] <- NA # Acrescento um missing na variável var
amostra <- svydesign(ids = ~ ID, data = exemplo, weights = ~ peso)
svymean(~ var + var2, design = amostra, na.rm = TRUE)
svymean(~ var2, design = amostra, na.rm = TRUE)
```

No primeiro `svymean` obtemos:

```
        mean     SE
var  0.56224 0.3166
var2 5.07549 0.4867
```

Já no segundo (somente para var2):

```
       mean     SE
var2 5.0833 0.4393
```